# Mongodb traffic analysis

Tags: mongodb

I am experiencing very high traffic on a mongodb database, since we pay per traffic I would like to understand which queries/collections are responsible for most of the traffic to understand what we have to reduce.

I tried the common tools like **mongotop**, but that does show only the time calculating, which is not always the same as the reason for the high bandwidth. Also tried **wireshark**, but the data is simply too much to find the main source by hand.

When trying **mongoreplay** record the outcome is only around 10% of what is transferred (at least iptraf is sure it is much higher). Had to increase the --capSize to 60000 to stop the loss of packets.

Now I have my dump, but using mongoreplay monitor does end up in "unexpected EOF".

Any ideas on alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried auditing? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/auditing/